# How to find specific xml elements in c#3.0

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml string and I would like to save the element values to variables for use in my program, however I've not been able to extract the values from the elements.

What is the simplest way to search elements by name so I can retrieve the value?

The error I receive:

```
Error: Element '<TimeToStart>' was not found.
```

XML:

```
<base>
        <area>
                <zone>
                        <TimeToStart>0400</TimeToStart>
                        <TimeToEnd>1900</TimeToEnd>
                </zone>
                <section>
                        <computer>A</computer>
                        <name>Alpha</name>
                        
                </section>
                <section>
                        <computer>B</computer>
                        <name>Bravo</name>
                </section>
        </area>
</base>
```

C# (3.0)

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlStr)); 

while (r.Read())
                {
                    r.MoveToContent(); 
                    r.ReadStartElement("<TimeToStart>");
                    string timeToStart = r.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    r.MoveToContent();
                    r.ReadEndElement();
                }
```

Comment: Just use LINQ to XML. It is available in c# 3.0

Comment: `"TimeToStart"` - remove angle brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out. LINQ to XML.

**c#**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<base>
        <area>
                <zone>
                        <TimeToStart>0400</TimeToStart>
                        <TimeToEnd>1900</TimeToEnd>
                </zone>
                <section>
                        <computer>A</computer>
                        <name>Alpha</name>
                        
                </section>
                <section>
                        <computer>B</computer>
                        <name>Bravo</name>
                </section>
        </area>
</base>");
        
        var xelem = xdoc.Descendants("zone");
        string TimeToStart = xelem.Elements("TimeToStart").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        string TimeToEnd = xelem.Elements("TimeToEnd").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        
        Console.WriteLine(TimeToStart);
        Console.WriteLine(TimeToEnd);

        foreach (var el in xdoc.Descendants("section"))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("computer='{0}', name='{1}'"
              , el.Element("computer")?.Value
              , el.Element("name")?.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have not read into linq, I will check it out and try it.

Comment: Is it possible to differentiate between the two duplicate <section> elements? Would this go into a list?

Comment: @Bruce85, it is possible.

Comment: How would I get the first and second section into a variable?

Comment: how to save each value to a string array?
ie computer[0], computer[1] and name[0], name[1] 
I have tried assigning to a string array but cannot access the elements of the array with [el]